# PIL Image.size() not working

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have some simple code to load an image file in and then display it's size, using Pillow fork and their documentation on how to find image attributes.

This is a code snippet taken from a larger file, but I don't think any of the other parts should have any bearing on PIL. I need to get the image header file, size in particular so I can convert it into a particular format for a machine learning project that takes a particular input array. Below is what I understand the documentation to be telling me to do.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
print im
print im.size()
```

This is the error I get when I run this

```
  File "DataStorage.py", line 31, in <module>
    print im.size() 
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: `size` is an attribute, not a function. Just type `im.size` without the brackets.

Comment: Ah that was it, I'm such an idiot haha

Comment: @OliverW. Please post your comment as a solution so that the OP can accept it an mark the question closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size` is an attribute, not a method of the image object. Just type `im.size` without the brackets.

Note that this is basically hinted at by the error message:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

"callable" refers to the action of calling something, usually by adding parentheses `()` to an object. Here, the error message was pointing out that you were actually performing a calling operation like this:

```
(1,2)()  # attempting to "call" a tuple will result in a TypeError
```